# Escaping SQL Data Types in a CREATE TABLE statement

Tags: php, mysql, security

**Quick background**: We are creating a Form Builder for our web application. The goal of the builder is to allow our administrators to quickly add / modify forms on our page.  To ensure that the data collected by these forms is easily searchable for reports, we have decided to have the application create a table for each form that holds the user input data.

Being conscious of security, all our table names and column names are being properly escaped and surrounded with the proper quotes (back quotes ` for MySQL).  However, I don't know of any escaping or quoting for the Data Types in a CREATE statement.  We want to allow different data types to account for better indexing and searching, which means they are dynamically decided when the form is created/modified.

**Current Route** we're taking is to Whitelist the possible data types we are supporting, and to force any optional size input to be a number.  In this way, any malicious code couldn't create a BLOB column, and passing in a size for a VARCHAR of "128); DROP DATABASE;" would be turned into either a 128 or a 0 (I forget right now how PHP handles string to number conversions).

**I wanted to get some feedback, do you think this is adequate protection? Is there some way to write the SQL that it would protect us, similar to surrounding a table name in proper quotes?**

**Also, does anyone have an idea of what dangers there are with data type sizes?** I'm expecting potentially an issue with eating up a lot of space, but nothing with security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all seems good to me, just don't forget that the DECIMAL type required two inputs, the scale and precision.

Comment: Yes, we're working a sort of two step translation and santizing/securing.  The user is presented with simple data types, the form builder turns them into an arbitrary representation, then our database code turns them into actual SQL.  Example: User makes a field with type **MONEY**, the Form Builder changes it to **DECIMAL,12,2** and the Database makes it **DECIMAL(12,2)**.

Comment: Updated the question, are there any concerns with negative, 0 or large data sizes?  I'd expect 0 or negative to create SQL errors, and large sizes possibly causing bloat, but no security concerns.

Comment: I'd limit char and varchar to specific maximum sizes and automatically shift to MEDIUMTEXT and LONGTEXT if text gets too high. I'd also implement a warning in your form builder if a user seems to be using a lot of highsize fields...

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using PHP, Why don't you just **Sanitize** your user inputs using sanitization filters & do everything else your way! Do let us know if this works fine for you? The PHP functions that you are looking for are `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` or others like this. You can browse those here http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the filters.  In this case it would only be effective as part of sanitizing the data sizes. We'd still need to either make sure they are positive, within a range, or let SQL throw an error on creation.  The filtering can't do whitelisting and would actually allow any damaging SQL code into the column names as it's all string based.

Comment: right. I remember dealing with something like this a while back , will let you know what I had.